# accessing iphone camera via xcode 11 swift 5 ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, swift5

I am trying to access my `iPhone` camera via **the code below.** But when I run the application, I only get a white screen with my `square` image meaning the camera does not show up.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var camera = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    @IBOutlet weak var square: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let begin = AVCaptureSession()
      guard  let captureCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera,
        for: AVMediaType.video,
        position: .back) else { return }

        do {
            let start = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureCamera)
            begin.addInput(start)  
        }
        catch{
            print("error" )
        }
```

**It does not print out "error" anywhere**

Comment: did you add the permission on info.plist?

Comment: @AndresGomez yes I added the permission Camera usage description with a string, but it does not pop up when I start up the app

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to initialize a preview layer and add it to your view.

```swift
do {
    let start = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureCamera)
    begin.addInput(start) 
    let videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: begin)
    view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)
} catch{
    print("error" )
}
```

Comment: I get the same output as above.. still a white screen with the square